# How to dismiss IntelliJ notifications with the shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I import or open a new project, notification appear on the right side. How can I dismiss them with the keyboard?

[image: IntelliJ Notifications Screenshot]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Recently, a keymap was added for marking all notifications as read. It is blank by default, but you can set that to any shortcut you would like.[image]

Comment: Beautiful! I hope it will be included in the default keymap some day.

Comment: I set the alt+c for notification clear, now it's working like a charm. thank you @nVitius

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no shortcut for closing popups that appear as balloons on startup of IntelliJ.

What you can do is permanently disable them
File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | Notifications

For more information, please refer:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/notifications.html

Comment: Thanks Umang! It's a bit disappointing but I will disable the notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + tab, ctrl + a (Go to Event log)

Application Menu key (close to the right control key) and Clear All.

Note that this will clear all the Event Log, but at least it will dismiss those notifications.